# Showing a text field in the app bar in Jetpack Compose with Material3

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack-compose-material3, material3

Many Android apps feature a search box in the app bar / toolbar, that looks somewhat like this screenshot:

[image]

*How do I recreate something similar in Jetpack Compose + Material3?* I would like the text field to have these features:

- support showing a hint when the content string is empty (e.g. "Type your search...")
- auto-focus on the first composition, so that the keyboard is opened
- put the cursor at the end of the content string on the first composition

---

I tried to reproduce the same behavior in Jetpack Compose + Material3 by putting a `TextField` in the `title` of a `CenterAlignedTopAppBar` but the result does not look good. The text field uses the whole height of the app bar and has a grey background, and both of these things look odd.

[image]

Comment: You didn't include the screenshot

Comment: Apparently `<img>` tags do not work, even though they should...
Also, I already know the answer to this question, I will post it soon, but for some reason no "Answer your own question" button was shown to me while compiling the question (it should have, according to https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer).

Answer (score 4):

I came up with a `AppBarTextField` after some engineering, see the code below. I had to use the lower-level `BasicTextField` since the normal `TextField` is not customizable enough. The code having to do with theming and color was copied directly from `TextField`'s implementation, so that the theme's customizations apply normally to the components of the text field.

The parameters the `AppBarTextField` composable accepts are:

- `value`: the content string to show in the text field
- `onValueChange`: new values are passed here (remember to update `value`!)
- `hint`: the hint to show when the text field is empty
- `modifier`, `keyboardOptions` and `keyboardActions`: they are passed directly to `BasicTextField` and they behave the same as they would in a normal `TextField`. If you need to customize other `TextField` parameters just add them to the function signature and then pass them to `BasicTextField`.

The requested features are implemented:

- the **focus acquisition** was achieved with a `SideEffect`, so that it would only happen on the first composition
- putting the **cursor at the end** on the first composition required using a `TextFieldValue`
- the **strange-looking background** is not present anymore, since no `.background()` modifier is present (while it is in the normal `TextField`)
- the **hint** was added using by passing a `placeholder` to `TextFieldDecorationBox` in the `decorationBox` parameter (note that this was also possible with `TextField`)
- `TextFieldDecorationBox`'s padding is also now only `4dp`. Padding was added here (and not with a modifier on `BasicTextField`) since otherwise the **bottom line indicator** (which is, instead, displayed using the `.indicatorLine()` modifier) would not be shown correctly.

```kotlin
@OptIn(ExperimentalMaterial3Api::class)
@Composable
fun AppBarTextField(
    value: String,
    onValueChange: (String) -> Unit,
    hint: String,
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    keyboardOptions: KeyboardOptions = KeyboardOptions.Default,
    keyboardActions: KeyboardActions = KeyboardActions.Default,
) {
    val interactionSource = remember { MutableInteractionSource() }
    val textStyle = LocalTextStyle.current
    // make sure there is no background color in the decoration box
    val colors = TextFieldDefaults.colors(
        focusedContainerColor = Color.Unspecified,
        unfocusedContainerColor = Color.Unspecified,
        disabledContainerColor = Color.Unspecified,
    )

    // If color is not provided via the text style, use content color as a default
    val textColor = textStyle.color.takeOrElse {
        MaterialTheme.colorScheme.onSurface
    }
    val mergedTextStyle = textStyle.merge(TextStyle(color = textColor, lineHeight = 50.sp))

    // request focus when this composable is first initialized
    val focusRequester = FocusRequester()
    SideEffect {
        focusRequester.requestFocus()
    }

    // set the correct cursor position when this composable is first initialized
    var textFieldValue by remember {
        mutableStateOf(TextFieldValue(value, TextRange(value.length)))
    }
    textFieldValue = textFieldValue.copy(text = value) // make sure to keep the value updated

    CompositionLocalProvider(
        LocalTextSelectionColors provides LocalTextSelectionColors.current
    ) {
        BasicTextField(
            value = textFieldValue,
            onValueChange = {
                textFieldValue = it
                // remove newlines to avoid strange layout issues, and also because singleLine=true
                onValueChange(it.text.replace("\n", ""))
            },
            modifier = modifier
                .fillMaxWidth()
                .heightIn(32.dp)
                .indicatorLine(
                    enabled = true,
                    isError = false,
                    interactionSource = interactionSource,
                    colors = colors
                )
                .focusRequester(focusRequester),
            textStyle = mergedTextStyle,
            cursorBrush = SolidColor(MaterialTheme.colorScheme.primary),
            keyboardOptions = keyboardOptions,
            keyboardActions = keyboardActions,
            interactionSource = interactionSource,
            singleLine = true,
            decorationBox = { innerTextField ->
                // places text field with placeholder and appropriate bottom padding
                TextFieldDefaults.DecorationBox(
                    value = value,
                    innerTextField = innerTextField,
                    enabled = true,
                    singleLine = true,
                    visualTransformation = VisualTransformation.None,
                    interactionSource = interactionSource,
                    isError = false,
                    placeholder = { Text(text = hint) },
                    colors = colors,
                    contentPadding = PaddingValues(bottom = 4.dp),
                )
            }
        )
    }
}
```

---

Here is an example usage:

```kotlin
var value by rememberSaveable { mutableStateOf("initial content") }
CenterAlignedTopAppBar(
    title = {
        AppBarTextField(
            value = value,
            onValueChange = { newValue -> value = newValue },
            hint = "A hint..."
        )
    },
    navigationIcon = /* the back icon */,
    actions = /* the search icon */
)
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: TextFieldDefaults.textFieldColors and  TextFieldDefaults.TextFieldDecorationBox now are deprecated

Comment: Thank you for letting me know! I edited the answer according to Android Studio's suggestions, and checked that the app bar still works the same way as before.